# How to allow NodeJS app live on external IP

Tags: node.js, google-compute-engine

I am trying to run my NodeJS App on the google cloud compute engine. But I just can access the preview page of the app. When I tried to access app through external IP. There is nothing happened.
I has use this command to add new firewall rule:

```
gcloud compute firewall-rules create default-allow-http-8080 \
    --allow tcp:8080 \
    --source-ranges 0.0.0.0/0 \
    --target-tags http-server \
    --description "Allow port 8080 access to http-server"
```

Comment: 1) What is the error you see? 2) Try accessing the server from within the VM first. 3) A commonly encountered problem with GCE: you must bind your the server socket to 0.0.0.0 instead of the external IP.

Comment: Oh, I found the problem. I run my server on the google cloud console, not in my instance. So when I access to the External Ip of the instance, there's nothing happened.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out my problem. When I accessed to the google cloud console, I though that is my instance console, the I installed my app in this. That's why when I tried to access the IP of the instance, there's nothing happened.